# How to add 301 redirect for a request with %20 at end of URL

Tags: asp.net, url, redirect, encoding, global-asax

Hi my site is written in .Net and I've discovered there are a few sites who incorrectly link to my site with a %20 symbol at the end of the URL.  For example their hyperlink is http://www.mysite.com/%20

This will always go to my 404 page and I've noticed that this happens to a lot of other big sites eg http://www.google.com/%20 will hit a 404.

When I try this locally I've put a breakpoint in Application_BeginRequest in global.asax to try and deal with the request however it doesn't even get this far, it just gives me a directory listing on screen and changes the URL in the address bar to "http://www.mysite.com/ /"

Comment: I'd say it's *their* job to fix the links, not yours to patch up stuff every time somebody links to `http://www.yoursite.com/£$Ylolumadbro£$`

Answer (score 0):

Check out the config section from this blog.The part of httpError redirection might be of relevance to you:
http://deepeshsomani.wordpress.com/2011/08/16/how-to-resolve-file-size-error-for-files-whose-size-is-larger-than-specified-in-web-config/

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't resolve the problem, my request doesn't even reach Application_BeginRequest so I can't even parse the URL to remove the %20 from the end